# SAP Eclipse Debugging and Json viewer for variable content

Tags: eclipse, debugging, abap, json-view

I have installed a JSON plugin in Eclipse that was tagged as editor and viewer 
[image]

Unfortunately after restart when debugging ABAP variables, the JSON viewer is not offered. Just the standard 5 offerings.

[image]

**Is there a way when debugging abap variables that to contain JSON content to see the content formatted?**

I can use Ctrl-A Ctrl-C and paste into a second when with open JSON file,
but that is cumbersome to repeat every time you wish to view a variable.

Comment: I think it's impossible with ADT. On regular Eclipse variables it should be *New Detail Formatter* item in context menu, but on ABAP variables it's absent.